# Coverity string_null false positive cannot be suppressed at the source

Tags: coverity

I have a C function that Coverity incorrectly flags as a `string_null_source` (i.e., the source of a non-null-terminated string). I'm asking for help in suppressing the error at the source. Some error checks are elided below.

```
int
source_func(const char *filename, char **contents)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int length, read_len;
    int rc = 0;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    ... error checking ...

    length = ftell(fp);
    ... error checking ...

    if (length == 0) {
        *contents = NULL;
    } else {
        *contents = calloc(length + 1, sizeof(char));
        ... error checking ...
        rewind(fp);

        read_len = fread(*contents, 1, length, fp);
        ... error checking ...
    }

bail:
    if (fp != NULL) {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Coverity identifies this function as a `string_null_source` because `Function "fread" does not terminate string "*contents".` However, the array was created by `calloc()`, which sets every byte to 0. So it's inherently null-terminated when we call `fread()` with one byte less than the array size.

The problem is that I can't get Coverity to stop throwing a `string_null` error when the caller passes `*contents` to another function that expects a null-terminated string:

```
static bool
caller(xmlNode *root, const char *sigfile)
{
    bool passed = FALSE;
    char *expected;
    int rc = source_func(sigfile, &expected);

    ... ensure rc == 0, which implies that expected is null-terminated ...

    passed = target_func(root, expected);
    free(expected);
    return passed;
}
```

Coverity complains: `Event string_null:     Passing unterminated string "expected" to "target_func", which expects a null-terminated string`, and identifies `source_func()` as the source.

---

I'm asking for help in suppressing the error. I've tried the following:

- Adding `// coverity[string_null_source:FALSE]` (and `// coverity[string_null_source:SUPPRESS]`) above the `fread()` line
- Adding `// coverity[-string_null_taint:arg-1]` above the `source_func()` definition

In each case, the error still appears in the analysis results.

I need to suppress the false positive at the `source_func()` level. There may be many callers, and I should not have to add `// coverity[string_null:FALSE]` annotations at each caller.

Comment: Unfortunately, suppressing a finding with a source annotation only works in the function where the finding is reported, not in a callee, even when the callee is the source of the erroneous inference.  If you're willing to change the code, you could just add a statement after the `fread` to redundantly add a `NUL` terminator.  Otherwise, I don't know if suppression is possible in this case (I'm not familiar with annotations like `string_null_taint:arg-1`).

Comment: Bummer :( Per the checker reference, `[-string_null_taint]` says "this function doesn't return a non-null-terminated string. And I figured event suppression in the callee would do the same thing -- "there's no string_null_source for the caller to observe and throw a string_null". I guess not. // Yeah, may have to redundantly null-terminate after `fread()`. The project lead really hates doing things like that to appease static analysis, but it might be the only way to address the issue at the source (unless someone else has ideas).